# install gcc 4.9 under suse10, "checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no"

Tags: c++, gcc, opensuse, suse, gcc4

I install gcc 4.9 by the following step

```
wget ftp://mirrors.kernel.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-4.9.0/gcc-4.9.0.tar.gz
tar -zxvf gcc-4.9.0.tar.gz
cd gcc-4.9.0 
./contrib/download_prerequisites
cd ..
mkdir gcc-build-4.9.0
cd gcc-build-4.9.0
../gcc-4.9.0/configure --enable-checking=release --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib
```

when I run the last command, it show the error message and stop

```
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln works... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for libatomic support... yes
checking for libcilkrts support... yes
checking for libitm support... yes
checking for libsanitizer support... yes
checking for libvtv support... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc... yes
checking for gnatbind... no
checking for gnatmake... no
checking whether compiler driver understands Ada... no
checking how to compare bootstrapped objects... cmp --ignore-initial=16 $$f1 $$f2
checking for objdir... .libs
configure: WARNING: using in-tree ISL, disabling version check
configure: WARNING: using in-tree CLooG, disabling version check
*** This configuration is not supported in the following subdirectories:
     gnattools target-libada target-libgfortran target-libgo target-libffi target-libbacktrace target-zlib target-libjava target-libobjc target-boehm-gc
    (Any other directories should still work fine.)
checking for default BUILD_CONFIG... bootstrap-debug
checking for --enable-vtable-verify... no
checking for bison... bison -y
checking for bison... bison
checking for gm4... no
checking for gnum4... no
checking for m4... m4
checking for flex... flex
checking for flex... flex
checking for makeinfo... makeinfo
checking for expect... no
checking for runtest... no
checking for ar... ar
checking for as... as
checking for dlltool... no
checking for ld... ld
checking for lipo... no
checking for nm... nm
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strip... strip
checking for windres... no
checking for windmc... no
checking for objcopy... objcopy
checking for objdump... objdump
checking for readelf... readelf
checking for cc... cc
checking for c++... c++
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for gcj... no
checking for gfortran... gfortran
checking for gccgo... no
checking for ar... no
checking for ar... ar
checking for as... no
checking for as... as
checking for dlltool... no
checking for dlltool... no
checking for ld... no
checking for ld... ld
checking for lipo... no
checking for lipo... no
checking for nm... no
checking for nm... nm
checking for objdump... no
checking for objdump... objdump
checking for ranlib... no
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for readelf... no
checking for readelf... readelf
checking for strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for windres... no
checking for windres... no
checking for windmc... no
checking for windmc... no
checking where to find the target ar... host tool
checking where to find the target as... host tool
checking where to find the target cc... just compiled
checking where to find the target c++... just compiled
checking where to find the target c++ for libstdc++... just compiled
checking where to find the target dlltool... host tool
checking where to find the target gcc... just compiled
checking where to find the target gcj... host tool
checking where to find the target gfortran... host tool
checking where to find the target gccgo... host tool
checking where to find the target ld... host tool
checking where to find the target lipo... host tool
checking where to find the target nm... host tool
checking where to find the target objdump... host tool
checking where to find the target ranlib... host tool
checking where to find the target readelf... host tool
checking where to find the target strip... host tool
checking where to find the target windres... host tool
checking where to find the target windmc... host tool
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
```

the error is "checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no"
any idea?

Comment: That's not an error message. The script ran successfully and created a Makefile. Just run `make`.

Comment: Have an upvote for using the `contrib/download_prerequisites` script and not trying to install the prerequisites yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a comment already mentioned, there is no error. The next step is to actually start building the compiler, and then install it. E.g. something like

```
# How many cpu's to use
NCPUS=4
make -j $NCPUS && make install
```

Note that as you haven't specified a prefix for your configure command, the default will be `/usr/local`, which might not be what you want. So I'd recommend rerunning configure, and adding something like `--prefix=/home/sleepworm/gcc-install-4.9.0`

Also, why are you building 4.9.0 when 4.9.2 with some bugfixes has already been released?

FWIW, the "checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no" thing can be changed by passing `--enable-maintainer-mode` to configure. It does enable some extra things, such as regeneration of some files etc., which are of interest only if you wish to develop gcc, rather than develop *with* gcc.

Comment: With no `--prefix` the default is `/usr/local/` which probably won't overwrite the system compiler (but you're right to say that overwriting the system compiler is a bad idea, and I always prefer to use an explicit `--prefix` anyway). I wish I could give you another upvote for questioning the choice of 4.9.0 rather than 4.9.2 ... I don't understand why so many people do that.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Oops, you're of course right about the default prefix.